# PackageKit: *** Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2

Tags: package

I have an installer built in "Packages" tool. While installing, **Couldn't postix_spawn: error 2** message is showing.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

*[Please find the following installer.log file for more in details]*

```
PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Feb 13 12:49:12 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <1 packages, destination=/>
Feb 13 12:49:12 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: packages=(   "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Users/efi/Desktop/FCC/OSX/FieryColorCloud.pkg#FieryColorCloud.pkg>")
Feb 13 12:49:15 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Users/efi/Desktop/FCC/OSX/FieryColorCloud.pkg#FieryColorCloud.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/692B6502-401B-46BD-ADB6-F1E52BFA3115.activeSandbox/Root, uid=0)
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Using trashcan path /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/PKInstallSandboxTrash/692B6502-401B-46BD-ADB6-F1E52BFA3115.sandboxTrash for sandbox /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/692B6502-401B-46BD-ADB6-F1E52BFA3115.activeSandbox
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/692B6502-401B-46BD-ADB6-F1E52BFA3115.activeSandbox/Root (2 items) to /
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac install_monitor[20439]: Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Developer, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac install_monitor[20439]: PackageKit: Locking applications
Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.ZLdi87/Scripts/com.efi.FieryColorCloud.3qlsuM
 Feb 13 12:49:22 asutos-mac installd[465]: ******PackageKit: *** Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2******
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac install_monitor[20439]: Re-included: /Applications, /Developer, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “FieryColorCloud.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/efi/Desktop/FCC/OSX/FieryColorCloud.pkg#FieryColorCloud.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.efi.FieryColorCloud, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “FieryColorCloud.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cFieryColorCloud.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Users/efi/Desktop/FCC/OSX/FieryColorCloud.pkg#FieryColorCloud.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.efi.FieryColorCloud";
    }
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installer[20435]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “FieryColorCloud.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Users/efi/Desktop/FCC/OSX/FieryColorCloud.pkg#FieryColorCloud.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.efi.FieryColorCloud, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “FieryColorCloud.pkg”.}
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=20435, uid=0 (/usr/sbin/installer)
Feb 13 12:49:23 asutos-mac installd[465]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
Feb 13 12:49:24 asutos-mac installer[20435]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

Answer (score 0):

`errno=2` is `ENOENT` on macOS.

This can be caused by the #! directive that starts the postinstall script specifying a program that does not exist on the destination system. You should verify that the postinstall script in the package specifies the full path to an interpreter that exists on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, there could be something wrong in your shell script (most likely about "hash-bang" i.e. #! directive).

Try below steps:

1. Find all the preinstall and postinstall installer-scripts in your source code.
2. For each of the preinstall/postinstall script:
   a. Copy the entire script content to a new file (say preinstall_new/postinstall_new) except the #! directive.
   b. Type in #!/bin/bash or other interpreter which is being used (do not copy, write using keyboard) at the top of preinstall_new/postinstall_new file.
   c. Make preinstall_new/postinstall_new files as executable (`chmod +x preinstall_new`)
   d. Replace the original preinstall/postinstall script with newly created preinstall_new/postinstall_new script files (`mv preinstall_new preinstall`)
3. Trigger the build and verify the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues or I think.
anyway I found how fix it surfing on internet.
I dont take any credits.
I tried following what the user "Kienz" said on:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-7836

If is going to get deleted here the ctrl + c ctrl + v

{After that change the "hg log" works. But you can't pull/push because of "mercurial_credential_manager.py" doesn't work with Python3. How can I disable "mercurial_credential_manager.py"?

Please fix Sourcetree that it works with Python3.}

After I just waited 20s and pressed on sourcetree > preference > mercurial tab the button "Reset to integrated mercurial"
Changed the error log into "Mercurial Incorporated 4.6.1"

This worked for me 26/07/2022
Sorry if the explanation isnt enough, but is just that!

There will be other problems, I started using the terminal for the git operation, at least SourceTree will help you visualy.